# Different JSON output by customer

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

**Problem Statement:**
Different customers want different JSON output (schema), to fit to their needs. Currently have implemented Spring Cloud Gateway to route to different customers, but using same JSON format.

**Desired Outcome:**
Although underlying source of data(properties) is same/single (inbound message) for all customers, different customers should be able to be configured to receive custom JSON output (POST to endpoint) based on their needs.

Tried using different filters to generate output structure and apply to route, but it is causing multiple model objects with duplication.
Looking for better solutions.